# wordpress very fast ajax request loading with two methods

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, performance

Need to make a very fast ajax request loading and we have ideas,

But want to know are we can do that ? and how ?

## Methos #1

1-Extract WordPress loop results as a variable $results.

2-Save $results (that html code) as a transient.

3-Retrieve this HTML $results to load faster.

## Method #2

1-Return ajax loop results of page#2

```
    $page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;
 $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'paged' => $page,
'orderby' => 'DESC',
);
```

2-Add this results to target div by append.

3-If we click again to get results of page#3

add this results to target div with hiding page#2 results div.

4-If clicked back hide page#3 results div and show page#2 div

Can you help ?

Comment: Here's the best recommendation for speed in a situation like this: Don't do AJAX.  Instead, store the data pre-loaded into the page in a script CDATA block (see [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)), and when people click, simply grab that data (already loaded) and display it.

Comment: You could use wp-rest api, some queries are faster because they don't load all WordPress http://v2.wp-api.org

Comment: @cale_b, Did you mean using wp_localize_script( 'site_vars', 'ajaxUrl', $ajaxUrl ); 
if so we did but we need to store loaded results to get it after that without load admin-ajax again